# Nesting IF function too many

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have tried this function and keep getting either a #Value error or Too Many Entries error. I'm trying to say that if cells C17:18 and C21 and C25:C31 and C33 and C36:C44 are blank, enter  text "Bill", if any of these have any value enter text "Hunter"

Here is the IF formula.

```
=IF(C17:C18="",IF(C21="",IF(C25:C31="",IF(C33="",IF(C36:C44="","Bill","Hunter"),"Hunter"),"Hunter"),"Hunter"),"Hunter")
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel can easily handle ten or more IFs inside each other, that is not your issue. Probably there is a syntax error somewhere in the line.

However, as all your ELSE cases are to be treated identically, there are better ways to handle it - for example, using AND. Try `IF(AND(your condition list),"Bill","Hunter")`.

Note that to check an area for being empty, you cannot simply check `C12:15=""` - this will only check the first cell, or will try to build a matrix formula, where each cell is matched with the respective cell from the next `IF`, which is not what you want. That could be the reason you get an error message, as the number of cells in each IF don't match between the various`IF`s. To accomplish what you want, you should use `COUNT(...) = 0` (or`COUNTA` or `COUNTIF`)

Comment: Thank you. I ended up having to enter each cell like C12="", C13="" ... ETC.

Comment: @EricHarp Well, no, you didn't _have_ to. You could have taken this answer's advice and written `=IF(COUNTA(C17:C18,C21,C25:C31,C33,C36:C44)>0,"Hunter","Bill")`, which is likely much simpler and faster to construct.